# java.lang.NullPointerException - onModifiedTouchEvent

Tags: android

The following exception happens on android framework:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onModifiedTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1270)
at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1209)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7249)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1954)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1902)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7429)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3358)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3303)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4444)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4423)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4515)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am I doing that is causing a crash on the framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `KeyboardView` without setting the `OnKeyboardActionListener`:

```
mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new OnKeyboardActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    }

}
```